# Card flip animation on PopupWindow or DialogFragment

Tags: android, card-flip

I am trying to apply card flip animation on ViewGroup inside `PopupWindow`. I am using `AnimatorSet` to apply animation over `ViewGroup`. Animation is happening within the bounds of the window. And part of window going out of window bounds are clipping. Any suggestions to avoid clipping?

I have found solution, but other solutions are welcome. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `scalX` and `scalY` properties of `objectAnimator`. When animation starts, I scale down window from value 0.9 to 0.5 for half of animation time. And again scale window from 0.5 to 0.9 for remaining animation time. As window size is reduced, window bounds perfectly fit inside clipping region during animation. This solved my problem. Below is the additional code in `card_flip_right_out.xml` from [this example](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/cardflip.html)

```
    <objectAnimator
        android:duration="200"
        android:propertyName="scaleY"
        android:valueFrom="0.9"
        android:valueTo="0.5" >
    </objectAnimator>
    <objectAnimator
        android:duration="200"
        android:propertyName="scaleX"
        android:valueFrom="0.9"
        android:valueTo="0.5" >
    </objectAnimator>
```

Below code added in `card_flip_right_in.xml`

```
<objectAnimator
    android:duration="199"
    android:propertyName="scaleY"
    android:valueFrom="0.5"
    android:valueTo="0.9" >
</objectAnimator>
<objectAnimator
    android:duration="199"
    android:propertyName="scaleX"
    android:valueFrom="0.5"
    android:valueTo="0.9" >
</objectAnimator>
<objectAnimator
      android:duration="1"
    android:propertyName="scaleY" 
    android:startOffset="199"
    android:valueTo="1" >
</objectAnimator>
<objectAnimator
    android:duration="1"
    android:propertyName="scaleX"
    android:startOffset="199"
    android:valueTo="1" >
```